# SoundCloud - 401 Unauthorized Error - Authenticating without the SoundCloud Connect Screen

Tags: c#-4.0, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I'm new to SoundCloud and have been following the developers documentation in [Authenticating without SoundCloud screen](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#authenticated-user).

However when my application sends the request I recieve a 401 Unauthorized error. In the documentation it specifies to check that the client_id or access_token is not missing and its not.

I can't figure out what is the issue here. I've checked the following:

1. Register Application - Check
2. Pass client_id and client_secret - Check

Here is my code that calls to the sound cloud server:

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Here are the values of the request object:

AuthenticationLevel     MutualAuthRequested
CachePolicy                {Level:BypassCache}
ConnectionGroupName null
ContentLength             -1
ContentType                  "application/json"
Credentials                    null
Headers                         {Content-Type: application/json}
ImpersonationLevel       Delegation
Method                           "POST"
PreAuthenticate              false
Proxy                              {System.Net.WebRequest.WebProxyWrapper}
RequestUri                     {https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token?client_id=############&client_secret=###########&grant_type=password&username=#######&password=########}
Timeout                          100000
UseDefaultCredentials   false

After the call I receive a 401 Unauthorized error, I even tried following [Geek Life's](http://www.geeklife.ch/dev/soundcloud-client-c/) blog but received the same error.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: dear can you shear your code . i am trying to connect to soundcloud using c# but no idea how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are sending the client credentials in the query string of the request. You must send them in the request body instead.

Comment: thanks for the nudge in the right direction. Added the parameters to the message body, change content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and received a token :)